# "Reset" For loop in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I have the following code

```
private List<CheckBox> list = new List<CheckBox>();
//Displays toppings in receipt
        foreach (CheckBox cbToppings in gbToppings.Controls)
        {
            if (cbToppings.Checked == true)
            {
                list.Add(cbToppings);
                iToppings++;

            }

        }

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {

            txtToppingsReceipt.Text += Convert.ToString(list[i].Text + Environment.NewLine);

        }
```

I have a groupbox with checkboxes in them, and the goal is to display the checked items in a multiline textbox when a button (btnOrder) is clicked. That part works perfectly for the first time, however, right now, when I click the btnOrder again, it does not clear the original output, despite me putting txtToppingsReceipt.Clear();.

I have another button which basically resets all fields, and that the clear textbox code is under that button. However no matter where I put that code, it simply does not want to clear the box after everytime btnOrder is clicked.

Am I doing something wrong? Will you guys be able to help me, I guess, reset the loop after every time it runs? If I put "break;" in the for loop, the code only runs once, and refuses to cooperate the second time I click btnOrder.

I'm new to programming so I may be getting ahead of myself. Either way, hopefully you guys can help me figure this thing out...

Comment: You must be doing something wrong if the code doesn't work.  What error are you getting?  You should use a RadioButton inside a groupbox which will allow only one radiobutton to be checked at one time.  If you want multiple items check then use CheckBox.  To uncheck all boxes put them into a List : List<CheckBox> boxes = new List<CheckBox>();  boxes.Add(cbToppings); boxes.Add(anotherBox);  foreach(CheckBox box in boxes){box.Checked = false;}

Comment: Where's the code that does the clearing?

Comment: box.Checked = false;

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils the code that does the clearing of the textbox is literally txtToppingsReceipt.Clear().

Comment: @jdweng No physical errors... It works, just not the way I want it to.

Comment: That's not the point. Where it's at and how you're using it is however.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils my bad. I have a button, called btnReset, and when it's clicked it just has txtToppingsReceipt.Clear(); Im not exactly sure what else you may need...

Comment: Add txtToppingsReceipt.Clear(); at the top of foreach loop. outside foreach.

Comment: @ShahidIqbal tried that, unfortunately still does the same thing... thanks though

Comment: @Unicorn13601 - Where is `list` defined? You have to clear that too. You don't show us how you're doing that in your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity oops my bad, I think I added it now? to the original post? How do I clear that?

Comment: @Unicorn13601 - That's a field-level variable. You need to move it in to your method.

Comment: @Unicorn13601 - Here's the single line you need that eliminates all that code: `txtToppingsReceipt.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, gbToppings.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Checked == true).Select(x => x.Text));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look something like this:

```
void MethodName()
{
    List<CheckBox> list = new List<CheckBox>();
    foreach (CheckBox cbToppings in gbToppings.Controls)
    {
        if (cbToppings.Checked == true)
        {
            list.Add(cbToppings);
            iToppings++;
        }
    }

    txtToppingsReceipt.Text = "";
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        txtToppingsReceipt.Text += list[i].Text + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

That way you're creating a new `list` each time and you're clearing the `txtToppingsReceipt` text before rebuilding it.

Please note that you didn't show us your full method so I don't know what name you've called it.

Or even better, like this:

```
void MethodName()
{
    txtToppingsReceipt.Text = "";
    foreach (CheckBox cbToppings in gbToppings.Controls)
    {
        if (cbToppings.Checked == true)
        {
            txtToppingsReceipt.Text += list[i].Text + Environment.NewLine;
            iToppings++;
        }
    }
}
```

You could have written your code like this though:

```
var list = gbToppings.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Checked == true).Select(x => x.Text).ToList();
iToppings = list.Count;
txtToppingsReceipt.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Enigmativity, it works now perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply start with `txtToppingsReceipt.Text = "";` to clear the textbox.

```
txtToppingsReceipt.Text = "";
list.Clear();
//Displays toppings in receipt
foreach (CheckBox cbToppings in gbToppings.Controls)
{
    if (cbToppings.Checked == true)
    {
        list.Add(cbToppings);
        iToppings++;
    }
}

for (Int32 i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    txtToppingsReceipt.Text += Convert.ToString(list[i].Text + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

If would not suggest to use a multiline text box for keep adding the line. Use a rich text box and use `rtb.AppendText`

Comment: I've tried doing that with the = " ";, but it doesn't work either, I think it makes sense if I have to clear the list too?

Comment: Yes. That's why I added list.Clear() right after .Text="";

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `+=` operator to append string, make use of `=` operator to assign changed value of `txtToppingsReceipt.Text`. I have refactor code and will work as expected.

```
string totalToppings = string.Empty;

foreach (CheckBox cbToppings in gbToppings.Controls)
{
    if (cbToppings.Checked == true)
    {
        totalToppings += cbToppings.Text + Environment.NewLine;
        iToppings++;
    }
}

txtToppingsReceipt.Text = totalToppings;
```

Comment: Ideally you should not be doing this either, as string is immutable. StringBuilder is the way to go.